# Azure functions keeps being triggered

Tags: azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-durable-functions

I have a weird behavior for both Azure function (Orchestration) and with Azure Service Bus trigger (Queue). both running on App Service Plan Standard with timeout > 10hours

I used chaining like this for both scenarios:

```
Azure Function 1 --> Azure function 2
```

if the function executes within few minutes it works with no issues but with long running code > 15 mins the function does not dequeue the message and keeps restarting. any ideas

.Net Core 3.1
ServiceBus Queue trigger and Orchestration.

Comment: whats the update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Bus message is locked while the function is running. Normally the lock is automatically renewed by the function runtime (for a configured maximum time). Please check your `host.json` and the setting `maxAutoRenewDuration` (which is 5 minutes by default and should not be increased). If the lock is not renewed by the runtime the message will be 'consumed' again by another function instance.

[More details in the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior)

Consider to make your functions run shorter or introduce intermediate 'states' in your work flow.