# Azure service bus queue trigger function is getting inactive and starts automatically if manually access

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

Azure service bus queue trigger is getting inactive without throwing any exceptions.

If i just access that function (not start or restart) then automatically starts processing message queue.

How can we find root cause of this issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Refer this @SunnyDewangan's [Post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/blob-trigger-function-does-not-fire-unless-you-visit-the-portal/ba-p/807948) to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

*Basically when we deploy our functions to azure from local our `localsettings.json` file not uploaded . We need to add the connection string manually. Make sure that you have added properly in your environment once deployed*.
*To add it goto Function> Configuration >Application settings.*

[image]

*So for the similar issue, Thank you *@Sebastian Achatz* as mentioned here in this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063547/azure-functions-keeps-being-triggered) posting the same suggestion here so that it can be beneficial for other community members*.

> While the function is in use, the Service Bus message is locked.
> Typically, the function runtime renews the lock automatically (for a
> configured maximum time). Please check the maxAutoRenewDuration and
> your host.json (which is 5 minutes by default and should not be
> increased). The message will once again be "consumed" by another
> function instance if the lock is not renewed by the runtime.

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **SO THREAD**|[***Azure Function (Service Bus Trigger) Not Getting started when a new message comes into the service bus queue***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063547/azure-functions-keeps-being-triggered) .
- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) .